# Can't get an alert() to fire on successfully posting to database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, angular, alert, crud

I am learning how to use a backend so forgive me if this is elementary, it seems like I'm missing something simple. I am trying to create a simple CRUD app to learn so I chose to make a blog platform that I can incorporate into my website later.

I am using Angular, Node and Express, and PostgreSql.

I can successfully post entries into the database. I can see them on Postico when I click Enter. I just can't seem to figure out how to fire an alert that notifies if the entry was posted successfully or not. Right now I have the alert in the Angular service on a .success etc, but I have a feeling that's wrong. When I was searching for the answer here other people had it in the controller but I tried that and it didn't work.

Here's the relevant code I have:

**createEntry.html**

```
  <form ng-submit="createBlogEntry(blog)">
  <h2>Title:</h2>
      <input type="title" ng-model="blog.title"></input>
    <br>
  <h3>Author:</h3>
      <input type="author" ng-model="blog.author"></input>
    <br>
  <h3>Photo:</h3>
      <input type="imageUrl" ng-model="blog.imageUrl"></input>
    <br>
  <h3>Content:</h3>
    <textarea type="content" rows="5" cols="50" ng-model="blog.content">
    </textarea>
    <br>
  <button type="submit">Save Entry</button>
  </form>
```

**createEntryCtrl.js**
The angular controller

```
angular.module("blog").controller("createEntryCtrl", function($scope, adminService) {

    $scope.createBlogEntry = function(blog){
        adminService.createBlogEntry(blog);
    }

});
```

**adminService.js**
The Angular service:

```
angular.module("blog").service("adminService", function($http) {
```

this.createBlogEntry = function(blog) {

```
$http.post('/api/createBlogEntry', blog)
    .success(function(data) {
      alert("Entry Posted");
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      alert("Error in Posting");
    })
  }

});
```

**index.js**
The Server Index (minus irrelevant endpoints)

```
// EXTERNAL MODULES //
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var massive = require('massive');

// CONFIG //
var config = require('./config');

// EXPRESS //
var app = module.exports = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + './../dist'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// MASSIVE //
var massiveUri = config.MASSIVE_URI;
var massiveServer = massive.connectSync({
    connectionString: massiveUri
});
app.set('db', massiveServer);
var db = app.get('db');

var dbSetup = require('./services/dbSetup');
dbSetup.run(); 

// CONTROLLERS //
var userCtrl = require('./controllers/userCtrl');
var blogCtrl = require('./controllers/blogCtrl');

// Blog Endpoints //
app.post('/api/createBlogEntry', blogCtrl.createBlogEntry);

// CONNECTIONS //
var port = config.PORT;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

**blogCtrl.js**
Node Controller:

```
var app = require('./../index');
var db = app.get('db');

module.exports = {

createBlogEntry: function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(res);
    var blog = req.body;
    db.blogs.blog_create([blog.title, blog.author, blog.imageUrl, blog.content], function(err, blog) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    })
  }

};
```

**blog_create.sql**
The Sql:

```
INSERT INTO blogs (title, author, imageUrl, content)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In success you need receive a 2xx code status to be triggered

Try this :

```
db.blogs.blog_create([blog.title, blog.author, blog.imageUrl, blog.content], function(err, blog) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    }else{
        res.send(200); //Everything is ok !
    }
});
```

Hope this help !
And sorry for my english!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I appreciate it. 

That did work, alert() now fires and it saves to the database!

Do you always have to res.send(200) for .success to work? That would make sense

Comment: Normally in crud's apps after saving an item into a db (it means a insert or update), if there is no error, the response is the item (that you send to save) but why get the same item than i send ? because after an operation into a db, the item could be modified adding new parameters (ej : id, timestamp, etc), and these parameters could be usefull on view (ej : order a list of items by timestamp, provided in db), doing a res.send(blog) its send by default a 2xx code status, thus is not necesary call res.send(200)

Answer (score 0):

Your service could return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Doing so, you could do like that:

adminService.js:

Change this:

```
    $http.post('/api/createBlogEntry', blog)
        .success(function(data) {
          alert("Entry Posted");
        })
        .error(function(data) {
          alert("Error in Posting");
        })
      }
    });
```

To:

```
return $http.post('/api/createBlogEntry', blog);
```

And in you Controller:

```
angular.module("blog").controller("createEntryCtrl", function($scope, adminService) {

    $scope.createBlogEntry = function(blog){
        var promise = adminService.createBlogEntry(blog);
        promise.then(
            function(res) { alert("Entry Posted"); },
            function(res) { alert("Error in Posting"); }                
        );
    }

});
```

You can see promises in angular [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Is this what you were talking about?

Hope it can help you. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this, I studied promises and it kind of went over my head.

Another commenter pointed out I was missing a res.send(200) for .success to work. That worked and so does your solution with a .then promise, but what are the advantages to using a promise instead?